# MVC Include path not valid error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, include

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    var userEmail = User.Identity.Name;
    var model = db.Staffs.Where(i => i.Email == userEmail).Include("Histories").Include("CurrentApplications").FirstOrDefault();


    return View(model);
}
```

I got the following error for the line `var model = db.Staffs.Where(i => i.Email == userEmail).Include("Histories").Include("CurrentApplications").FirstOrDefault();` but i don't know why I got it.

**Error**

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'StaffPortalDBModel.Staff' does not declare a navigation property with
>   the name 'Histories'.

**Staff class**

```
public partial class Staff
{
    public int StaffID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> AllocatedLeave { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BalanceLeave { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<History> Histories { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<CurrentApplication> CurrentApplications { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: better use writable collections (ICollection etc) instead of IEnumerable

Comment: @eyeballs why staff is partial?

Comment: @M.Azad it was auto generated with the edmx when i added the database to my program

Comment: Why not use a ViewModel? Why use Include? Just create a ViewModel and encapsulate what you need using a Select => new xxx

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to use ICollection and not IEnumerable when defining Navigation properties.  This may be the issue.

I'd also recommend (assuming your version of Entity Framework is high enough that it is supported) to use strongly typed Includes so that if you change your property in Staff.cs you'll get a compile time error.

ie: .Include(s => s.Histories)

Comment: I tried changing to ICollection and use strongly typed includes but it still doesn't work for me D:

Comment: You have a partial keyword in the Staff class.  Are you using an edmx?  I'm not that fluent with those diagrams as I normally use Code First, but are the navigation properties present in the model?

Comment: yeap im using edmx. Uh all that is in my model is shown the class model in my question

Comment: @eyeballs I'm surprised that the Staff class would have generated with IEnumerables.  Did you create the Staff file listed above manually? If you open your model edmx file, does it show a relationship between Staff and Histories?